# Radeon 5450 crashes when running streaming video via HDMI

Tags: video, graphics-card, hdmi, amd-radeon

So I have a box that's been working fine for months, with a Radeon 5450 video card running a standard small monitor via VGA. Just bought my first-ever HDMI-capable TV, and plugging the HDMI cable into it, it works fine... until I try to stream video on it.

Netflix is fine. Simple animations, like the spectrometer in Foobar, is fine.

But if I try anything else with video streaming -- YouTube, or TV streaming -- after a few seconds I'll get a total freeze with a stuttering sound. Zero keyboard response. If I use the reset button, I get a freeze on the BIOS startup screen. A hard reboot -- full power down, wait 10 seconds -- and everything boots up again normally.

I'm mystified, but I also don't know much at all about HDMI, hardware controllers, etc.

I'm attaching a full system rundown (captured by Speccy) and some screenshots of the Catalyst control center that seem to pertain.

I do have:
- a fully updated BIOS
- all updates for Windows XP, which is what this system is running on
- the latest video drivers for my video card

Again, it seems to be only streaming video that crashes the system. Which, since this is basically what this setup is for, is kind of disheartening. Ideas?

Speccy rundown:

http://pastebin.com/DmmmGjK7

Images from Catalyst Control Center:

[image: Display Properties]
[image: HDMI properties]
[image: VPU recover - what is this?]
[image: Information Center 1]
[image: Information Center 2]

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card drivers seem to be outdated, can you [update your drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows%207%20-%2032) and then try this out again ?

Comment: That's odd -- I went through the whole process of downloading the Radeon "detect your hardware" software, having it auto-detect and download the most up-to-date driver for the card, and installing it. Should I have done all that manually instead of trusting the Radeon detection software?

Comment: it shouldn't matter as long the correct package is installed ... so does it fix your issue ?

Comment: Your link goes to Win7/8 drivers, and this box is running XP, as stated in the original post. I believe I have the most recent drivers for XP and this video card.

Comment: Ok, does your computer crash when you stream video now ?

Comment: Yes -- and I've confirmed that I really have the newest XP drivers installed. I'm letting Memcheck +86 run all day just in case I'm having a concurrent issue and this is a coincidence/symptom of bad memory.

Comment: ...which it isn't. For now, I've just removed the HDMI cable and am running the computer via a VGA cable directly to the TV's VGA input, eschewing having a "regular" monitor on it.